# Remove content links (internal and external), but exclude post at specific categories

Tags: php, functions, links

```
    add_filter('the_content', 'removelink_content',1);

function removelink_content($content = '')
{
    preg_match_all("#<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>#i",$content, $matches);
    $num = count($matches[0]);for($i = 0;$i < $num;$i++){
        $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i] , $matches[2][$i] , $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

It works, but I would like to exclude some categories. That is, that the code works only on posts that are not in an excluded category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude certain categories from the filter function that removes links from the post content, you can modify the function to check the categories of the post before removing the links.

Here is an example of how you can modify the function to exclude certain categories:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'removelink_content',1);

function removelink_content($content = '') {
  // Get the categories of the current post
  $categories = get_the_category();
  
  // Set up an array of excluded category IDs
  $excluded_categories = array(2, 5, 8);
  
  // Check if any of the categories of the current post are in the excluded categories array
  $excluded = false;
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $excluded_categories ) ) {
      $excluded = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // If the post is not in an excluded category, remove the links from the content
  if ( ! $excluded ) {
    preg_match_all("#<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>#i",$content, $matches);
    $num = count($matches[0]);
    for($i = 0;$i < $num;$i++){
      $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i] , $matches[2][$i] , $content);
    }
  }
  
  return $content;
}
```

In this example, the function first gets the categories of the current post using the `get_the_category()` function. It then sets up an array of excluded category IDs (in this case, the IDs 2, 5, and 8). The function then checks if any of the categories of the current post are in the excluded categories array using the `in_array()` function. If the post is in an excluded category, the `$excluded` variable is set to `true`.

If the `$excluded` variable is not set to `true`, the function proceeds to remove the links from the content as before. If the `$excluded` variable is set to `true`, the function does nothing and returns the content as-is.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This really does the magic!!! <3 Any way to record that in the database?

Comment: @unopermanente I'm not sure i under the question, to record the excluded categories?